# Reload the tables AJAX/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using such Ajax code for reload the tables on my page:

```
//ajax page section reload
$(document).on("click", '.section-reload #send', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    NProgress.start();
    $('#tasks-tab').load(document.URL +  ' #tasks-tab');
    NProgress.done(); 
});

$(document).on("click", '.dynamic-reload', function (e) {
    var reload = $(this).data('reload');
    if(reload) {
        $('#'+reload).load(document.URL + ' #'+reload, function(data) {
            easyPie();        
        });             
    }
});    

$(document).on("click", '.dynamic-form .send', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('form').validator();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    valid = true;
    var thisinput = $(this);
    $('input').filter('[required]:visible').each(function(i, requiredField){
        if($(requiredField).val()=='') {
            valid = false;
            $('.modal').animate({
                scrollTop: $(requiredField).offset().top
            }, 500);
            $(requiredField).parent().addClass("has-error");
            thisinput.text().replace('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> ', '');
        }
    });

    if(valid) {
        var content = $('textarea.summernote-modal').summernote('code');
        var url = $(this).closest('form').attr('action'); 
        var baseurl = $(this).closest('form').data('baseurl');
        var active = $(this);
        var data = new FormData($(this).closest('form')[0]);
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false, 
            data: data,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if(typeof data.error === 'undefined') {
                } else {
                    console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
                }
            var reload = active.closest('form').data('reload');
            var reload2 = active.closest('form').data('reload2');
            var reload3 = active.closest('form').data('reload3');
            var reload4 = active.closest('form').data('reload4');
            var reload5 = active.closest('form').data('reload5');

            if(reload) {
                $.get(document.URL, function(data) {
                    $('#'+reload).parent("div").html($(data).find('#'+reload));
                    $('#'+reload2).parent("div").html($(data).find('#'+reload2));
                    $('#'+reload3).parent("div").html($(data).find('#'+reload3));
                    $('#'+reload4).parent("div").html($(data).find('#'+reload4));
                    $('#'+reload5).parent("div").html($(data).find('#'+reload5));
                    $('#gantData').html($(data).find('#gantData'));

                    $('#'+reload).velocity("transition.slideDownOut", { duration: 300 });
                    $('#'+reload2).velocity("transition.slideDownOut", { duration: 300 });
                    $('#'+reload3).velocity("transition.slideDownOut", { duration: 300 });
                    $('#'+reload4).velocity("transition.slideDownOut", { duration: 300 });
                    $('#'+reload5).velocity("transition.slideDownOut", { duration: 300 });

                    $('#'+reload + ' .checkbox-nolabel').labelauty({ label: false });
                    $('#'+reload2 + ' .checkbox-nolabel').labelauty({ label: false });
                    $('#'+reload3 + ' .checkbox-nolabel').labelauty({ label: false });
                    $('#'+reload4 + ' .checkbox-nolabel').labelauty({ label: false });
                    $('#'+reload5 + ' .checkbox-nolabel').labelauty({ label: false });

                    $('#'+reload).velocity("transition.slideUpIn", { duration: 300 }); 
                    $('#'+reload2).velocity("transition.slideUpIn", { duration: 300 }); 
                    $('#'+reload3).velocity("transition.slideUpIn", { duration: 300 }); 
                    $('#'+reload4).velocity("transition.slideUpIn", { duration: 300 }); 
                    $('#'+reload5).velocity("transition.slideUpIn", { duration: 300 });

                    //reload Modal
                    modalfunc();
                    keepmodal = active.data('keepmodal');
                    if(keepmodal === undefined){
                        $('#mainModal').modal('hide');
                    } else {
                        active.closest('form')[0].reset();
                        $("#mainModal .note-editable").html("");
                    }
                    //remove loader icon from button
                    var value = active.text().replace('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> ', '');
                    active.html(value);
                    //reload timers on task details
                    $( ".timer__span" ).each(function() {
                        timertime = $(this).data("timertime");
                        timerid = "#"+$(this).attr("id");
                        timerstate = $(this).data("timerstate");
                        startTimer(timerstate, timertime, timerid);
                    });
                    $(".todo__close").click();
                    sorting_list(baseurl);
                    hideClosedTasks();
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(formData) {
            var reload = active.closest('form').data('reload');
            var reload2 = active.closest('form').data('reload2');
            var reload3 = active.closest('form').data('reload3');
            var reload4 = active.closest('form').data('reload4');
            var reload5 = active.closest('form').data('reload5');    
            if(reload) {
                $.get(document.URL, function(data) {
                    $('#'+reload).parent("div").html($(data).find('#'+reload));
                    $('#'+reload2).parent("div").html($(data).find('#'+reload2));
                    $('#'+reload3).parent("div").html($(data).find('#'+reload3));
                    $('#'+reload4).parent("div").html($(data).find('#'+reload4));
                    $('#'+reload5).parent("div").html($(data).find('#'+reload5));
                    $('#gantData').html($(data).find('#gantData'));

                    $('#'+reload).velocity("transition.slideDownOut", { duration: 300 });
                    $('#'+reload2).velocity("transition.slideDownOut", { duration: 300 });
                    $('#'+reload3).velocity("transition.slideDownOut", { duration: 300 });
                    $('#'+reload4).velocity("transition.slideDownOut", { duration: 300 });
                    $('#'+reload5).velocity("transition.slideDownOut", { duration: 300 });

                    $('#'+reload + ' .checkbox-nolabel').labelauty({ label: false });
                    $('#'+reload2 + ' .checkbox-nolabel').labelauty({ label: false });
                    $('#'+reload3 + ' .checkbox-nolabel').labelauty({ label: false });
                    $('#'+reload4 + ' .checkbox-nolabel').labelauty({ label: false });
                    $('#'+reload5 + ' .checkbox-nolabel').labelauty({ label: false });

                    $('#'+reload).velocity("transition.slideUpIn", { duration: 300 }); 
                    $('#'+reload2).velocity("transition.slideUpIn", { duration: 300 }); 
                    $('#'+reload3).velocity("transition.slideUpIn", { duration: 300 }); 
                    $('#'+reload4).velocity("transition.slideUpIn", { duration: 300 }); 
                    $('#'+reload5).velocity("transition.slideUpIn", { duration: 300 }); 

                    //reload Modal
                    modalfunc();
                    keepmodal = active.data('keepmodal');
                    if(keepmodal === undefined) {
                        $('#mainModal').modal('hide');
                    } else {
                        active.closest('form')[0].reset();
                        $("#mainModal .note-editable").html("");
                    }
                    //remove loader icon from button
                    var value = active.text().replace('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> ', '');
                    active.html(value);
                    //reload timers on task details
                    $( ".timer__span" ).each(function() {
                        timertime = $(this).data("timertime");
                        timerid = "#"+$(this).attr("id");
                        timerstate = $(this).data("timerstate");
                        startTimer(timerstate, timertime, timerid);    
                    });
                    $(".todo__close").click();
                    sorting_list(baseurl);
                    hideClosedTasks();
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
    }
});
```

The problem is where I'm reloading the tables, they're loosing sorting/search elements as a part of the tables ability. Datas are ok... It seems like WebBrowser loosing some JavaScript functions/ability of the tables.

If I'll refresh whole page, everything back to normal.
Can You please analize the code, and give me some advice?

I'm using PHP/JavaScript/Ajax/datatables.

Comment: if your using jquery for sorting on a page you first need to intialise the sorting elements, once you refresh the tables you would need to reinitialize the sorting elements.

Comment: It would be very helpful to debug, if you put your HTML and CSS code ?